# Phonegap Geolocation jumps

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation

I have started to create an exercise tracking application referring to [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/build-an-exercise-tracking-app-persistence-graphing/)
and all works just fine.

But after I stop the tracking and goes to the map, I see that the kilometers is much more then the kilometers I have passed for sure and the map shows that i have was in some points that for sure I couldn't be there...

(Because i do not have the image from my phone i have simulate the results of the map with the attached image...)
The code is identical to the tutorial code (With the correction of the bug that dealing with delete the var - for those who know this tutorial...))
What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: From my experience playing with any GPS receiver device when creating a location-based application (it doesn't matter which platform): whenever you stays static at one place or when it suffers multipath interference, the GPS receiver will give jumpy locations. It is advised to include a distance filter to ignore any relative distance more than what you anticipate every GPS refresh.

Comment: See **Some Limitations** paragraph in http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0103/differential1of2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the same as [eee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980521/eee) - that Android will intermittently delivers wildly inaccurate positions while using GPS, so the best thing is to use an accuracy filter, something like this:

```
var MinimumAccuracy = 20; // metres
var options = { maximumAge: 0, timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: true };
var watchID;

function onSuccess(position){
  // Reject udpate if accuracy is not sufficient
  if(position.coords.accuracy > MinimumAccuracy){
      console.warn("Position update rejected because accuracy of"+position.coords.accuracy+"m is less than required "+MinimumAccuracy+"m");
      return;
  }

  /* else, do something with position */

}

function onError(error){
  // Log the error
  console.error("Error while retrieving current position. Error code: " + error.code + ",Message: " + error.message);
}

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition( onSuccess, onError, options );
```